# Hamcrest number comparison using between

Tags: java, hamcrest

Is there a way in Hamcrest to compare a number within a number range? I am looking for something like this:

```
assertThat(50L, is(between(12L, 1658L)));
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

An alternative to Jeff's solution is to use `both`:

```
assertThat(50L, is(both(greaterThan(12L)).and(lessThan(1658L))));
```

I think that's quite readable. You also get a good error message in case the check failed:

> Expected: is (a value greater than <50L> and a value less than <1658L>)
>   got: <50L>

Comment: I didn't find the import for _both_ statement. Can someone help?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez It's in org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers

Comment: Thanks. It was not appearing for me because LambdaJ uses hamcrest-all-1.1, which doesn't have this implementation. I've found it at version 1.2 or above.

Comment: This also works well with java.util.Date comparisons since Date implements Comparable

Answer (score 26):

I don't believe `between` is part of the core hamcrest matchers, but you could do something like this:

```
assertThat(number, allOf(greaterThan(min),lessThan(max)));
```

That's still a little ugly, so you could create a helper method between

```
assertThat(number, between(min,max))
```

and `between` looks like

```
allOf(greaterThan(min),lessThan(max))
```

Still not a fantastic solution, but it reads like a hamcrest matcher.

If you can't find one that's publicly available, it would be trivial to write your own `between` matcher http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial.

Answer (score 17):

If you're dealing with integers, you should consider using the `closeTo` method:

```
assertThat((double)nclient, is(closeTo(nserver, 1d)));
```

unfortunately, there's no `closeTo` for integers, but every 32 bit integer is representable by a double, so you can simply cast them to doubles, and carry on.

This is not exactly equivalent to `between`, but can sometimes be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [Cirneco extension](https://github.com/ozimov/cirneco). It has `between()`, `betweenInclusive()` and more. These matchers also apply to other objects that implements `Comparable` (like `Date`).

Following your example, it will be:

```
assertThat(50L, between(12L, 1658L));
```

and if you want the two bounds to be included:

```
assertThat(50L, betweenIncluded(12L, 1658L));
```

or if you want just one of the bounds to be included:

```
assertThat(50L, betweenLowerBoundIncluded(12L, 1658L));  
assertThat(50L, betweenUpperBoundIncluded(12L, 1658L));
```

---

You can use the following dependency for a JDK7-compliant project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java7-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or the following if you are using JDK8

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
  <artifactId>java8-hamcrest-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```